# Redirect to register if Guest checkout is disabled Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

From admin (sales/checkout) I set up the option Allow Guest Checkout to no.
When (after I added a product in cart) I click on place order now, the message: `Guest checkout is disabled Magento 2` is displayed.
I want to redirect to register page.

Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to achieve this:
Go to **Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration and set Require Emails Confirmation to yes** (you will see a pop-up with login/register form).